# Avoid image change on variation select for WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product-variations

In WooCommerce, how to avoid image change on selecting variations (of a variable products)?

Answer (score 1):

I modified the core add-to-cart-variation.js and add-to-cart-variation.min.js and changed two parts of the code that caused the image slide after variation change. It might not be a good idea to modify the core js file you might be able to dequeue the original and enqueue your new file version that you uploaded in the functions.php so the change you made will still be there on a WooCommerce update.

**add-to-cart-variation.min.js :**

replace:  `r.trigger("click"),`

WITH-->>  `/*r.trigger("click"),*/`

also replace:  `&&i.trigger("woocommerce_gallery_reset_slide_position")`

WITH-->>    `/*&&i.trigger("woocommerce_gallery_reset_slide_position")*/`

**add-to-cart-variation.js :**

replace:  `slideToImage.trigger( 'click' );`

WITH-->>  `//slideToImage.trigger( 'click' );`

also replace:  `$product_gallery.trigger( 'woocommerce_gallery_reset_slide_position' );`

WITH-->>    `/*$product_gallery.trigger( 'woocommerce_gallery_reset_slide_position' );*/`

Comment: This also breaks woocommerces abillity to set the price

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need image changed for variations you should remove images from variations assigned. I suppose it is embedded with plugin or theme features

Answer (score 0):

As the image change is mainly handle by Woocommerce gallery javascript (jQuery) as it's a live event on client side.

The only possible way, should be to remove all images from variations, adding them only in the parent variable product.

**If you need to display a variation product image** in cart and email notifications, you will use the following code:

```
// Parent product variation image on cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'filter_order_item_thumbnail', 20, 2 );
function filter_order_item_thumbnail( $image, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ) {
        $parent = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
        $image = $parent->get_image();
    }
    return $image;
}

// Parent product variation image on email notifications 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', 'filter_order_item_thumbnail', 20, 2 );
function filter_order_item_thumbnail( $image, $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    if( $product->is_type('variation') ) {
        $parent = wc_get_product($item->get_product_id());
        $image = $parent->get_image(array(32, 32));
    }
    return $image;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, how to "remove all images from variations" in one shot ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in this theme directory `wp-content/themes/<YOUR_THEME_NAME>/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` and add this code

```
<?php
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.5
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

$new_available_variations = $available_variations;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($new_available_variations);$i++){
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() );
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id() );
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['url'] = $image_url;
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['src'] = $image_url;
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['full_src'] = $image_url;
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['gallery_thumbnail_src'] = $image_url;
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['thumb_src'] = $image_url;
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['url'] = $image_url;
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['url'] = $image_url;
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['full_src_w'] = $image_src[1];
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['full_src_h'] = $image_src[2];
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['thumb_src_w'] = $image_src[1];
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['thumb_src_h'] = $image_src[2];
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['src_w'] = $image_src[1];
    $new_available_variations[$i]['image']['src_h'] = $image_src[2];
}
$attribute_keys  = array_keys( $attributes );
$variations_json = wp_json_encode( $new_available_variations );
$variations_attr = function_exists( 'wc_esc_json' ) ? wc_esc_json( $variations_json ) : _wp_specialchars( $variations_json, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true );

// echo '<pre>', print_r($new_available_variations,1), '</pre>';

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo $variations_attr; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', __( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
                                    array(
                                        'options'   => $options,
                                        'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                                        'product'   => $product,
                                    )
                                );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            <?php
                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_single_variation. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
                 *
                 * @since 2.4.0
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' );
```

Comment: This really needs some explanation